# Trying to get jquery .ajax to recognize my PHP JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json

Calling :

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://blahblah/cow.php',
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: {
            'guid': '111',
            'score': 592,
            'initials': 'tod'
        },
        success: function (data) {

            try {
                //alert(data + " -- " + data.length);
                if (data.length > 0) {
```

Doing this in my php page:

```
echo ('[{error : "' . $error . '", rank : "' . $usersRank . '", totalScores : "' . $totalScores . '"}]');
```

But JQ just keeps seeing this as text and won't recognize it as JSON... what am I doing wrong?

Ive tried getting rid of square brackets (nothing), using json_encode - but that was adding quotes to my variables and it still didnt work, tried adding headers(COntent type) to the php page... Argh!  Cant figure this out!

DO I HAVE TO CALL DIE or something like that (kind of like Response.end)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what I am doing wrong but I finally just did this... I stopped using Content-type in php or dataType in ajax call and just took the data 'string' and called

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

on it and then perform what I wanted to on it.

Answer (score 2):

The `data` contains value of the `responseText` of the transport object. For `success` callback to treat it as JSON you need to either explicitly set `content-type` header on your php page to be `application/json` or `type` property of the ajax config object to `json`.

Alternatively you could use `$.getJSON`, which is a shorthand for `$.ajax({dataType:"json"})`.

Comment: header('Content-type: application/json');
 echo json_encode($data);
Setting THAT sends me back object Object with no .length...? But the json_encode also doesnt return square brackets... ?  Is that a problem?

Comment: Why is that a problem? Square brackets would construct an array (an actual array, and not whatever PHP calls "array"), which in your case would always have `.length == 1`. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: if I put that content type header in my php file, I get length = undefined...when I try and alert the data is just says object Object... if I try and make dataType:"json", I get undefined...
Using .Net, Ive always just called .ajax, type:POST and been fine... :(

Comment: I understand that, but why do you need `length`? What is the actual condition you are trying to check? If all you need to know is if the data has something in it, then `if (data)` would work just fine.

Comment: you mean `dataType` not `type`.  `type` should still be `POST` in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

JSON requries keys AND values to be quoted. You're only quoting values. Don't generate JSON by hand. It's far too easy to introduce syntax errors. Let PHP do it for you:

```
$data = array(
   'error' => $error,
   'rank' => $usersRank,
   etc..
);

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: {"error":"","rank":1,"totalScores":9}  -- this is what I am returning by using your code... see how my int's are not in quotes..?  Might that be why my JQ still doesnt recognize it as JSON?

Comment: numbers don't have to be quoted, but all strings do. it is HIGHLY unlikely that json_encode() would produce a json string that has syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `contentType: "application/json"` form the `$.ajax` call, and use `type: json` as @liho1eye suggests. If jQuery still complains about the format of your json response, get rid of the square brackets, or use `json_encode` as @MarcB says.